# Difference running java as java application vs run on server

Tags: java, eclipse, server

I can't quite get what is the difference between these two things. Is running Java as Java Application any similarities to running Java on a server?

I am using Eclipse and have made a few small school projects. First I always used to run Java as Java Application and now I'm running all my code on tomcat server.

I know what a server is, but I just don't see the difference here.

Comment: There really is no difference in terms of java itself. The only difference is that most server application are written in a way to stay alive and listen for incoming requests one way or the other but java itself does not care about that.

Comment: What is the context of this question?  Is some tool asking you a question or choice that you don't understand?

Comment: @DavidM.Karr I can't speak for the OP, but I have a problem where, when I run a Spring Boot on server, the server starts for the servlet doesn't initialize. Therefore, when I try to test the endpoint in the SpringBoot controller, it fails with HTTP 404. However, when I run the servlet as Java application, I can see in the console that Tomcat started AND the servlet as well. Now, when I test the same endpoint (Postman on directly on browser) it works perfectly. I don't understand why this is.